# logstash http_poller Header data

Tags: logstash

I am trying to replicate

```
curl 10.0.0.42 -d "some data"
```

in the logstash http poller but either there isn't a way of doing this or I haven't found the right search term to find it.

Can someone either confirm that there is no method of this or point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec` for executing commands and capture their output.

```
exec { 
    command => "curl 10.0.0.42 -d "some data"
    interval => 60 
}
```

This would execute the command every 60 seconds.